# How to access AppDelegate object and call method from other SwiftUI views

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, appdelegate

I am working with the **SwiftUI** app and I configured my Push Notification setup in AppDelegate and it's working fine like below:

```
Messaging.messaging().delegate = self

        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
          // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
          UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self

          let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
          UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
            options: authOptions,
            completionHandler: {_, _ in })
        } else {
          let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
          UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
          application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        }

        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
```

Now I have to move this code from app launch to TabBarView screen where I can request for permission once login success.

So for that, I have created func in **AppDelegate** file like this:

```
func enablePushNotification() {
        
        let application = UIApplication.shared

        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
          // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
          UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self

          let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
          UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
            options: authOptions,
            completionHandler: {_, _ in })
        } else {
          let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
          UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
          application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        }

        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    }
```

and calling it from `TabBarView()` like this:

```
init() {
        print("TabBar Init called")
        configurePushNotification()
    }

func configurePushNotification() {
        if let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate {
            appDelegate.enablePushNotification()
        }
    }
```

But I am not able to get the AppDelegate object here and It's unable to call appDelegate method from TabBarView().

Any suggestion here why I am not able to get the AppDelegate object or is there any other way to get it?

Comment: Try making the method a static func

Comment: Use the `@UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor` property wrapper to get the Application Delegate instance. Unrelated but `#available(iOS 10.0, *)` is pointless as SwiftUI is not available prior to iOS 13

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply but didn't get your point `@UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor` can you please give more details on how to use it? and yeah thanks for pointing out iOS condition will remove it.

Comment: Got your point now I can able to access it through @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor and Observable on the delegate. Thanks once again.